# How to escape charters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, escaping, sql-server-2014

I need a SQL function or query that can escape '\' (backslash) but only odd numbers of '\' (backslashes) from string.

For example:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) ='abc\df\\gh\\\eg\\\\yu'
```

I am using the SQL `Replace` function to escape the backslash (`\`) like this:

```
@str  = Replace(@str,'\','\\')
```

But the problem is it will replace the even numbers of sub strings too. But I only need it should replace only even number of sub strings having '\' from string.

Comment: Do you have an example output?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work. First you replace the sets of double slashes with some character that doesn't exist in your data. I chose the carat but you could chose any other character that works. Then you replace the slashes with a double, and finally replace the temporary character back to double slashes.

```
select replace(replace(Replace(@str,'\\','^'), '\', '\\'), '^', '\\')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple replaces:

```
SET @str = replace(replace(replace(@str, '\\', '~~~'), '\', '\\'), '~~~', '\\')
```

This assumes that `'~~~'` doesn't occur in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex+Stuff+PatIndex to get this as below:

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = 'abc\df\gh\\eg\\\y\u'
declare @i int = 1
--select @str
while 1=1
begin
    SET @i = patindex('%[a-z]\[a-z]%', @str)
    if @i <= 0 break    
    set @str = stuff(@str,@i+1, 1, '\\')
    --print @i
    --print @str
end

select @str
```

Modify the regular expressions as you like, if it has numbers, strings with capital characters etc..,